# Making Ajax calls from a localhost to my own server

Tags: ajax, blackberry, widget

I am making an simple Blackery Berry app (widget) which uses simple HTML/JS to retrieve data  from a page on my own server. The problem is that, the Ajax only works if the Ajax is called if it's on the same server.

I understand Ajax doesn't allow you to make calls if it is not on the same domain, however is there anyway to get around this? The widget will be on the person's BB and hence not on the same domain and I can't figure out how to make the Ajax work. Is there any .htacess rules perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you control the server, you can set headers that allow cross-origin requests. See for instance [this post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) on hacks.mozilla.org. I believe support for this is pretty much universal in modern browsers, though I don't know how it works on a Blackberry.